# Unable to click on Menu Bar>>Tools Menu in Mozilla Firefox using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, mozilla, menubar

How to click on Menu Bar>>Tools Menu of Mozilla Firefox using selenium Webdriver?

Comment: and please read [ask]

Comment: Webdriver is used only for web automation. If u need to change certain values try to set preferences or capabilities of desired browser.

Answer (score 0):

You CAN'T do something like this. You just can handle the HTML elements, events and simulate actions between your HTML and the user. Selenium works with the DOM, is used to test your web application not to interact with the browser as OS an app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
 Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_L);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_L);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);

    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
```

And then use the right arrow to move from one element to another.